# Delay email from Skilled Worker visa from inside the UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I have made an application to switch my visa from Graduate Route Visa to Skilled Worker Visa. I received the following response (delay email) from the Home Office today. What do I need to do? Is there any chance of visa refusal? Please guide me.[image: email screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only thing you can do is ask your sponsor to tell you what further information has been requested and when it will be / was provided to UKVI. There is of course always the possibility of a refusal, however this type of request can be made eg if there is a clear error or omission in the evidence and information with the application and certificate of sponsorship.

See [Skilled Worker caseworker guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/skilled-worker-visa-caseworker-guidance/skilled-worker-caseworker-guidance-accessible)